# Maven dependency in Mule project is not included in the build

Tags: mule, maven-3

I have installed a JAR in local maven repository (because no longer available in Mule repository) and added as dependency in POM file

```
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
          <artifactId>mule-module-rest-router</artifactId>
          <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I also have XML namespace and schema location defined as

```
<mule xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml"  xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
...
xmlns:rest-router="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/rest-router"
version="EE-3.6.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd
.....
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/rest-router http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/rest-router/current/mule-rest-router.xsd">
```

Deploying in Mule 3.6.1 using Maven project in Anypoint Studio, getting errors

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/rest-router/current/mule-rest-router.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
      at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaWarning(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
      at org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext.loadBeanDefinitions(MuleArtifactContext.java:106) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130) ~[spring-context-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451) ~[spring-context-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
      at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:86) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:105) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:135) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:90) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:84) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:217) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:76) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:187) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:62) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:57) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:310) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:330) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:155) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:256) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:78) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:275) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:150) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:100) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:152) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:15) ~[tooling-support-3.6.1.jar:?]
INFO  2016-06-08 10:37:09,903 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Disposing RegistryBroker
ERROR 2016-06-08 10:37:10,044 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'rest-router:router'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":response, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":legacy-abstract-exception-strategy, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-info-mapping}' is expected.
      at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
      at org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext.loadBeanDefinitions(MuleArtifactContext.java:106) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130) ~[spring-context-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451) ~[spring-context-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
      at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:86) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:105) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:135) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:90) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:84) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:217) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:76) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:187) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:62) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:57) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:310) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:330) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:155) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:256) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:78) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:275) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:150) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:100) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:152) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
      at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:15) ~[tooling-support-3.6.1.jar:?]
```

Upon investigation I found that mule-module-rest-router-1.2.jar is not included in the lib directory of deploy zip created in target directory. I have spent almost full day figuring out why this particular JAR is not getting included despite given in default scope of POM.xml. Please help!

Comment: try update dependency option in Anypoint studio.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it as an inclusion on the mule-appkit plugin:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.appkit</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-appkit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.appkit.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
                    <excludeMuleDependencies>true</excludeMuleDependencies>
                    <inclusions>
                        <inclusion>
                            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mule-module-rest-router</artifactId>
                        </inclusion>

                    </inclusions>
                </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Tried and worked but could you please explain what this plugin does and why is it needed? Surprisingly, it did not need version to be specified.

Comment: Yes it does not need version, it just needs the name id and group so it knows to include it. The reason is, the appkit used to make the mule archive by default exclude mule modules and have to be specifically included.

Comment: Does it mean that mule modules can not be included just by adding as dependency? and have to be included using this plugin?

Comment: Ryan, any thoughts pls?